# how to loop through an array using select statement in php

Tags: php, arrays, loops, select

This is my code. i want to print the output based on itemID in the database table. how do i print each of the output of each itemID using array and loop? What is the best way to do this?

```
<?php
$result=mysql_query("select * from item where itemID='1'") or die(mysql_error());
$get_row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
?>
<?php echo $get_row['No']; ?>.<?php echo $get_row['Item']; ?> :<?php echo $get_row['Unit']; ?> unit

<br>
</br>
<center>
    <table border="1" width="1000" height="80">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Nama</th>
                 <th>Jenama</th>
                 <th>Model</th>
                 <th>No_Siri</th>
                 <th>Tagging</th>
                 <th>Tarikh_Diterima</th>
                 <th>Remarks</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <?php
                $emp_query=mysql_query("select * from service_record where itemID='1' order by Nama");
                while($row=mysql_fetch_array($emp_query)){
                     $id=$row['service_record_id'];
                     $emp=$row['itemID'];
                ?>
                <tr class="del<?php echo $id ?>">
                    <?php
                    $result=mysql_query("select * from item  where itemID='1'")or die(mysql_error());
                    $row_emp=mysql_fetch_array($result);
                    ?>
                     <td><?php echo $row['Nama']; ?></td>
                      <td><?php echo $row['Jenama']; ?></td>
                      <td><?php echo $row['Model']; ?></td>
                      <td><?php echo $row['No_Siri']; ?></td>
                      <td><?php echo $row['Tagging']; ?></td>
                      <td><?php echo $row['Tarikh_Diterima']; ?></td>
                      <td><?php echo $row['Remarks']; ?></td>
                    </tr>
```

```
            <?php $result=mysql_query("select * from item where itemID='2'")or die (mysql_error());
        $get_row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
    ?>

            <?php echo $get_row['No']; ?>.<?php echo $get_row['Item']; ?> :<?php echo $get_row['Unit']; ?> unit


    <br>
    </br>

    <center>
        <table border="1" width="1000" height="80">



            <thead>
                <tr>


                    <th>Nama</th>
                    <th>Jenama</th>
                    <th>Model</th>
                    <th>No_Siri</th>
                    <th>Tagging</th>
                    <th>Tarikh_Diterima</th>
                    <th>Remarks</th>

                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>

                <?php $emp_query=mysql_query("select * from service_record where itemID='2' order by Nama");
                    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($emp_query)){ $id=$row['service_record_id']; $emp=$row['itemID'];  ?>

                    <tr class="del<?php echo $id ?>">
                        <?php
                            $result=mysql_query("select * from item  where itemID='2'")or die(mysql_error());
                            $row_emp=mysql_fetch_array($result);
                        ?>
                        <td><?php echo $row['Nama']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['Jenama']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['Model']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['No_Siri']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['Tagging']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['Tarikh_Diterima']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['Remarks']; ?></td>




                    </tr>
                    <?php }?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </center>

          <br>
</br>

  <br>
</br>
```

for now, i write the coding one by one according to the itemID=1, itemID=2 and so on. i dont know how to make the output display all the itemID in the database without write it one by one

[this is the example of picture that i want the output to display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rMMWK.png)

Comment: what is the problem ?! what do you mean best way?

Comment: where do you close while ?!

Comment: In the coding, i did not use loop and array because i don't know how to put it in the coding.

Comment: i think maybe i can use array and loop to get the output that i want

Comment: Did you try using one query like `"select * from item i join service_record s on i.itemID = s.itemID;"` and print whatever you need in `while()` loop?

Answer (score 0):

if you have only one row data than you can keep  inside while loop else you need to keep it outside the loop .

```
               <tr>
                while($row=mysql_fetch_array($emp_query))
                { 
                $id=$row['service_record_id']; 
                $emp=$row['itemID'];
                // use itemID='$emp' instead of itemID='1'
                    $result=mysql_query("select * from item  where itemID='$emp'")or die(mysql_error());
                    $row_emp=mysql_fetch_array($result);
                    ?>
                     <td><?php echo $row['Nama']; ?></td>
                      <td><?php echo $row['Jenama']; ?></td>
                      <td><?php echo $row['Model']; ?></td>
                      <td><?php echo $row['No_Siri']; ?></td>
                      <td><?php echo $row['Tagging']; ?></td>
                      <td><?php echo $row['Tarikh_Diterima']; ?></td>
                      <td><?php echo $row['Remarks']; ?></td>

                <?php } ?>  
                </tr>
```

Comment: i don't know how to explain more details. if you don't mind can you look at the picture that i have attach below the code. that is the output that i want to have.

Comment: it can't detect which itemID to display. it only display row for the nama,jenama,model,no_siri,tagging,tarikh_diterima and remarks but not it details

Comment: why you have use itemID='1' every where ? is this for testing purpose ??

Comment: yes it is for testing because itemID=1 is the id for the item. i need to display two different things. first, i need to display the item name. for example, the first item name is computer that have itemID=1, then under the item name which is computer, it will display the table that contains the data for the item name. the itemID is in item table in database while the data for the each itemID is in service_record table. the itemID is the foreign key for service_record. after that, it will display the item name for other item which are itemID=2, itemID=3,... and so on.